# I want to select a checkbox, how to obtain a xpath for the picture below anyone?

Tags: automated-testing, xpath

[image]

Please help me with the xpath for the above picture to select a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[image]

In this image you can see the xpath I used to locate the element in Firefox.

Comment: still it does not work on my side, is there any other solution for this?? Anyone

Comment: It would help if you share your full html and your selenium code and the actual error you get.